# Integration of Google Drive to Google Cloud storage through Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm integrating Google Drive with Google Cloud Storage using Colab. The Colab notebook is pretty simple and helpful.
There are 2 things I needed to know.
1. If there is any way to automate this integration using Google Colab.
2. How to solve the connection issue as it needs frequent reconnection.

I'm new to Google cloud Storage. Any information or links could be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever find a solution?